# How do I remove multiple git source controls from my project?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I was dragging some files from an Xcode project to a new Xcode project. Then I notice on the new Xcode project. There're now 2 source controls listed, one from the first Xcode project. The delete keyword is greyed when I right click on it.

[image: https://imgur.com/27vn6Xq]

How do I remove the git reference from the first Xcode project?

Answer (score 2):

Weird af. All I had to do was move the new Xcode project to any other folder. Then the extra working copy reference disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have dragged also a `.git` subfolder: that would explain the second repo being "created/visible" after your file move operation.

Removing that extra `.git` subfolder in your second directory (the one created by the move) should be enough to resolve the situation.

Comment: I only see 1 .git folder that belongs to the new project. I can't find anything related to previous Xcode

Comment: @TyrantBoy Yes: you should see only one .git for the new project. Maybe you ca n try and close XCode, move your original project elsewhere (with its nested .git folder) ,reopen XCode.

Comment: @TyrantBoy is the delete option which is grayed the one you see in http://www.sunzala.com/2017/10/27/use-github-xcode-9-0/ (search for "delete" in that page)